# Making transient (non-database) attributes in Django model available to template

Tags: django, oop, django-models

One of my models has attributes that are not stored in the database. Everything is fine at the view and model level but I cannot seem to  display these 'non-database' attributes in my template.

Here's some example code, an artificial example that mirrors the actual problem domain, to demonstrate the undesired behavior.

The view:

```
def odometer(request):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    for car in cars:
        car.read_meters()
    context = {'cars': cars}
    return render_to_response('odometer.html', context)
```

The models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True)

    def read_meters(self):
        for meter in self.meter_set.all():
            meter.read()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class Meter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)

    difference = 0
    previous = 0
    changed = False

    def read(self):
        # this is completely artificial. in the real application we would interface with the hardware
        # meter to get data
        try:
            previous_count = MeterReading.objects.filter(meter__id=self.id).order_by('-stamp')[0].count
        except:
            previous_count = 0
        self.previous = previous_count
        current_count = previous_count

        if (random.randrange(0, 2) == 0):
            self.difference = int(random.random() * 100)
            if self.name == 'Odometer' or (random.randrange(0, 2) == 0):
                current_count += self.difference
            else:
                current_count -= self.difference
                if current_count < 0:
                    current_count = 0
        if current_count > previous_count:
            self.changed = True
        new_reading = MeterReading()
        new_reading.count = current_count
        new_reading.meter = self
        new_reading.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class MeterReading(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(_('count'))
    stamp = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    meter = models.ForeignKey(Meter)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.count
```

And the template:

```
{% for car in cars %}
  <h2>{{ car }}</h2>
  {% for meter in car.meter_set.all %}
    <h3>{{ meter }}</h3>
    <p>Difference: {{ meter.difference }}</p>
    <p>Changed: {{ meter.changed }}</p>
    <ul>
      {% for reading in meter.meterreading_set.all %}
      <li>{{ reading }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is 'meter.difference' and 'meter.changed' don't output the correct updated values. What am I doing wrong? Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE: Updated code based on Daniel's answer:

The Car model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100, unique=True)

    def read_meters(self):
        for meter in self.meters:
            meter.read()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

    @property
    def meters(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_meters'):
            self._meters = self.meter_set.all()
        return self._meters
```

And the template:

```
{% for car in cars %}
  <h2>{{ car }}</h2>
  {% for meter in car.meters %}
    <h3>{{ meter }}</h3>
    <p>{{ meter.name }} difference: {{ meter.difference }}</p>
    <p>Changed: {{ meter.changed }}</p>
    <ul>
      {% for reading in meter.meterreading_set.all %}
      <li>{{ reading }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'd avoid adding dynamic attributes. I'd rather try to make `difference` and `changed` methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why you aren't seeing these values in your template is that every time you call `car.meter_set.all()` you get a completely new queryset straight from the database.

Django model instances don't have identity, so even though the `Meter` objects in one queryset have the same database values as the ones in another, they do not share any dynamic attributes.

One way to do this would be to cache the Meter objects within each Car, as I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712902/adding-mini-caches-to-django-models/1713562#1713562) on a recent question. Then instead of referring to `car.meter_set.all()` in the view, model and template, you would do `car.get_meters()` or whatever, and you would get the same set of objects each time, along with your dynamic attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar in my own code and it looks like the problem you're running into is happening in the `read_meter()` method and `odomoter()` view.

The `meter` and `car` objects that you're using to iterate through the QuerySets are falling out of scope, and the changes you make to their attributes is going with them.

When you display meter.difference and meter.changed in the template, Django's recreating those objects from the DB (and without the unsaved attribute values).

Hope that explanation is clear. Any reason not to save the values to the DB?

Comment: My reason for not saving the data is simply that it is transient. It just seems wrong to me to store data that will have to be calculated on the fly and will never be referenced again in a database field. Please note also that the example above is artificial and in the real application some of the transient data is hundreds of MBs in size. Thanks for your help.